# Where can I find data about alternative medicine use?

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for data about alternative and complementary medicine (CAM) use. I need something as detailed as possible. In this moment, I am looking for whatever country has complete and detailed time series.

I am aware of data about US ([link](https://nccih.nih.gov/research/statistics/NHIS)) but I was looking for some other country.